# How to edit file on virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I broke my `/etc/fstab` file on my guest system in VirtualBox. How can I correct it? I tried virt-edit, but I can't get it working.

Guest OS: Debian

Host: Ubuntu

Comment: You could try booting the VM from a recovery CD image (e.g. Ubuntu install disc), mounting the virtual drive, and fixing it through there.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Anything that would work on a real machine, would still work on a VM:

   - Use a rescue disk or live CD image to boot the system and correct your mistake.
   - Try booting into single-user mode - this should work, as long as your rootfs entry is correct and your distribution didn't mess up the filesystem hierarchy too badly.
   - Modify the kernel boot options to mount the proper rootfs and boot into `/bin/sh` directly.
2. It is possible to view the VirtualBox drives as a disk and mount the filesystems on the host - I have described such a process in [this old answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/a/210685/60384).

Answer (score 0):

You might also boot in single user mode and use `vi` or `zile` or `emacs` or `nano` (or some other terminal editor) to edit it